# What is the simplest post-quantum asymmetric cryptographic algorithm for key exchange?

Tags: public-key, key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography

This question has been burning in the back of my head for the past few days, and a quick Google search doesn't yield any usable results.

As the title suggests: What is the easiest-to-understand post-quantum asymmetric cryptographic algorithm that currently exists (as of 10 May 2021) for key exchange?

To establish common ground, assume that I understand everything from Khan Academy's Math Syllabus. On top of that, assume that I have gone through all of the undergraduate courses for MIT's Electrical Engineering & Computer Science courses.

Answer (score 6):

There is only one paper I know of which explains a post-quantum key exchange algorithm in such a way that a beginner could understand it, and that is for SIDH (Supersingular Isogeny Diffie-Hellman key exchange). The paper is called [Supersingular isogeny key exchange for beginners](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1321.pdf).

> **Abstract.** This is an informal tutorial on the supersingular isogeny Diffie-Hellman protocol aimed at non-isogenists.

Note that SIDH has been [badly broken](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/101290/54184), so it may not be fair to use it as an example.

If you don't care whether or not it is actually usable, then there's [pqRSA](https://cr.yp.to/papers/pqrsa-20170419.pdf) which is essentially just regular RSA with (completely impractical) parameters that make it post-quantum secure.

Comment: *“Post-quantum RSA is not what one would call lightweight cryptography: thecost of each new encryption or decryption is on the scale of $1 of computer time,many orders of magnitude more expensive than pre-quantum RSA.”* If he's not being hyperbolic here, does he really mean a straight ~week of processing on a CPU less than 10 years old?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Yes he does. See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59591/54184